# undefined reference to constructors and destructors

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I've only seen this caused by people not linking their class objects together at build time, but I have, and I'm unsure what the matter is.

the source:

```
//test.cpp
#include "Point.h"
#include "Sphere.h"
#include "Scene.h"


int main(){
    Sphere s;
    Scene sc;
    sc.img_plane.upper_left = Point(-1, 1, -3);
    sc.img_plane.upper_right = Point(1, 1, -3);
    sc.img_plane.lower_left = Point(-1, -1, -3);
    sc.img_plane.lower_right = Point(1, -1, -3);
    sc.width = 100;
    sc.height = 100;
    return 0;
}
```

the error:

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `Sphere::Sphere()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `Scene::Scene()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x192): undefined reference to `Scene::~Scene()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `Sphere::~Sphere()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `Scene::~Scene()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1d3): undefined reference to `Sphere::~Sphere()'
```

the Makefile:

```
CC = g++
SRC = ./src
BUILD = ./build

main : main.o Point.o colort.o Sphere.o Scene.o Ray.o HitRecord.o
    $(CC) $(BUILD)/main.o $(BUILD)/Point.o -o $(BUILD)/main

main.o : $(SRC)/test.cpp
    $(CC) -c $< -o $(BUILD)/main.o

Point.o : $(SRC)/Point.cpp $(SRC)/Point.h
    $(CC) -c $< -o $(BUILD)/Point.o

colort.o : $(SRC)/colort.cpp $(SRC)/colort.h
    $(CC) -c $< -o $(BUILD)/colort.o

Sphere.o : $(SRC)/Sphere.cpp $(SRC)/Sphere.h $(SRC)/colort.cpp $(SRC)/Point.cpp
    $(CC) -c $< -o $(BUILD)/Sphere.o

ImagePlane.o : $(SRC)/ImagePlane.cpp $(SRC)/ImagePlane.h
    $(CC) -c $< -o $(BUILD)/ImagePlane.o

Scene.o : $(SRC)/Scene.cpp $(SRC)/Scene.h
    $(CC) -c $< -o $(BUILD)/Scene.o 

Ray.o : $(SRC)/Ray.cpp $(SRC)/Ray.h
    $(CC) -c $< -o $(BUILD)/Ray.o

HitRecord.o : $(SRC)/HitRecord.cpp $(SRC)/HitRecord.h
    $(CC) -c $< -o $(BUILD)/HitRecord.o     

clean :
    rm $(BUILD)/*

test : main 
    $(BUILD)/main
```

Scene constructor is the same as the Sphere:

Sphere.h:

```
#ifndef SPHERE_H_
#define SPHERE_H_

#include "colort.h"
#include "Point.h"
#include "Ray.h"

class Sphere {
public:
    Sphere();
    virtual ~Sphere();
    Point center;
    double radius;
    color_t diffuse, specular;
    double intersection(Ray r);
};

#endif /* SPHERE_H_ */
```

Sphere.cpp:

```
#include "Sphere.h"

#include <math.h>

Sphere::Sphere() {

}

Sphere::~Sphere() {

}

...other class functions
```

Comment: I don't see `test.cpp` anywhere in your makefile. How do you comile that?

Comment: I forgot to post it, it's in the question now

Comment: Still something missing; when does test.cpp get compiled? That's the one that's generating the error messages.

Comment: @Pete It's in there now, target `main.o`

Comment: Okay. @FatalError has given you the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `main` rule:

```
main : main.o Point.o colort.o Sphere.o Scene.o Ray.o HitRecord.o
    $(CC) $(BUILD)/main.o $(BUILD)/Point.o -o $(BUILD)/main
```

Notice that although you mention Sphere.o as a dependency, you have not *linked* it.  You need to include it on the build line, too:

```
main : main.o Point.o colort.o Sphere.o Scene.o Ray.o HitRecord.o
    $(CC) $(BUILD)/main.o $(BUILD)/Point.o $(BUILD)/Sphere.o -o $(BUILD)/main
```

You probably also want to add the others, based on the fact that you list them as dependencies.

Comment: It looks like they need `Scene.o` too.